# scrapy can not follow full link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

```
scrapy shell ""https://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings/2/"
response
```

however I get

`2019-02-19 14:16:35 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-02-19 14:16:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-02-19 14:16:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.winemag.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-02-19 14:16:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings> from <GET https://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings/2/>
2019-02-19 14:16:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings> from <GET http://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings>
2019-02-19 14:16:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings/> from <GET https://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings>
2019-02-19 14:16:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings/> (referer: None)`

`<200 https://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings/>`

I can't figure out why is it not obtaining the full link, could someone provide me a suggestion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. I had to specify the USER_AGENT in the settings file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `winemag` redirects crawlers to its homepage:

```
⇾ curl -I 'https://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings/2/'
HTTP/2 301
[...]
location: http://www.winemag.com/wine-ratings
[...]
```

so it seems this would be the expected behavior from `scrapy`, which is following the redirects returned to it by the website you're accessing?

Comment: Thank you, this was right, the website was redirecting me because I have missed to identified myself by setting the USER_AGENT.